# Breeze EntityManager.executeQuery() not returning promise (or data?) in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, breeze

I am trying to use Breeze to get data from a server into an AngularJS app, and although the server is sending the JSON data, the client app is not getting it. The closest I've gotten to identifying the issue using the debugger is to see that the following function `getRemoteEntities()`, which is part of a Factory, should return a promise but instead returns an empty Object {} when called with a valid entityURL and jsonAdapter:

```
[...]
var manager = entityManagerFactory.newManager();
[...]
return { 
    getRemoteEntities: function (entityUrl, jsonAdapter) {

        var query = breeze.EntityQuery
            .from(entityUrl)
            .using(jsonAdapter);

        return manager.executeQuery(query)
            .then(function (results) {
                return results;
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                return $q.reject(error);
        });
    }
}
```

I have checked, and the code does use the Breeze Angular Service as described [here](http://breeze.github.io/doc-js/breeze-angular.html). I do not understand what is not working.

EDIT: Removing the `.using(jsonAdapter)` means that I am able to get and resolve the promise, suggesting that it might be doing something that messes it up. Here is an example (they all follow this pattern):

```
.value('jsonProfileResultsAdapter', new breeze.JsonResultsAdapter({

    name: "xyz", // mild obfuscation

    extractResults: function (data) {
        var results = data.results;
        if (!results) throw new Error("Unable to resolve 'results' property");
        return results;
    },

    visitNode: function (node, parseContext, nodeContext) {

        if (node) {
            if (node.person && node.assignments) {
                return {entityType: "EmployeeModel"}
            }
        }
    }
}))
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the `jsonAdapter` doing? That's an unusual feature (not wrong, just unusual). Maybe you're doing something inside it that blows up the promise.

Take it away and see what you get. If you get a promise, even a failed promise, then you're on to something.

Comment: Well, the purpose of the `jsonAdapter` is that the server is serving Smalltalk objects serialized to JSON. Looks like the `jsonAdapter` is mostly attaching an `entityType`? (I did not write them.) I tried taking the `jsonAdapter` out of the equation (e.g., simply `var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from(entityUrl);`) and I am now getting (and likely resolving) a promise but am unable to get the entities from the manager (probably because the `jsonAdapter` has been removed).